# C# linq expression. How to get different offsets and 'any' offset?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to read out the header of a file and compare it to a given signature. The start of the signature can have an offset.

This is my current function:

```
    public FileTypeVerifyResult Verify(Stream stream)
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        var headerBytes = reader.ReadBytes(SignatureLength + this.OffSet);

        return new FileTypeVerifyResult
        {
            Name = Name,
            Description = Description,
            IsVerified = Signatures.Any(signature =>
                headerBytes.Skip(this.OffSet).Take(signature.Length)
                    .SequenceEqual(signature)
            )
        };
    }
```

This currently works with one offset but extensions exists that can have multiple offsets. So my first thought was to make the `OffSet` property an `int[]` with all offsets but then I don't know if this can be easily build into this linq expression.

Also, the file can have the offset `any` (or any other value that means anywhere in the file like just `-1`). How could such a thing build in?

Comment: You need to dispose of your readers and streams.

Comment: Properties should not by typed as mutable arrays (e.g. `int[]`) because it is unclear if the property always returns the same array - or returns a new array on every call - and also doesn't indicate if the array is mutable or not. Instead, why not add an `params int[] offsets` parameter to your `Verify` method?

Comment: You should not blindly set `stream.Position = 0` because not every `Stream` is seekable (e.g. `NetworkStream` is not seekable). You need to check for `if( stream.CanSeek )` first.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to handle more offsets, this is my solution:

```
    protected List<int> OffSets { get; set; }

    public int OffSetLength => OffSets.Max(m => m);

    public FileTypeVerifyResult Verify(Stream stream)
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        var headerBytes = reader.ReadBytes(SignatureLength + OffSetLength);
        reader.Close();

        return new FileTypeVerifyResult
        {
            Name = Name,
            Description = Description,
            IsVerified = Signatures.Any(signature =>
                OffSets.Any(offSet => 
                    headerBytes.Skip(offSet).Take(signature.Length)
                        .SequenceEqual(signature))
            )
        };
    }
```

I don't think I can get the any/-1 offset in this function without rewriting everything.

Comment: Your code has runtime complexity of `O(n *m)`, you can **significantly** improve that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the case where a swiss knife is not what you want, Linq is good for many things, but it really doesn't add any value to the problem at hand IMHO because writing such a query will make ones eyeballs bleed, but here is my take at the problem itself with a sparse use of LINQ if at all :)

I have allowed myself to deduct missing items that were not supplied and rationalize naming a bit.

```
public class FileType
{
    public class FileTypeVerifyResult
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsVerified { get; set; }
    }

    public class Signature
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Actual signature
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] Payload { get; set; }
        public int Length { get => Payload.Length; }
        public List<int> OffSets { get; set; }
    }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Signature> Signatures { get; set; }

    public FileTypeVerifyResult Verify(Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream == null) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(stream));
        if(stream.CanSeek)
            stream.Position = 0;
        else
            //TODO: Consider if we need this: throw new ArgumentException("Stream does not support seek", nameof(stream));
        
        var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        int wasRead = stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        if (wasRead == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Unable to read from stream");
        
        foreach (var signature in Signatures)
        {
            foreach(var offset in signature.OffSets)
            {
                if(offset == -1)
                {
                    //TODO: read signature length from each position first 0, then 1 until what is left is less than length of signature and if it fits
                    return createResultObject(true);
                }

                var candidateBytes = new byte[signature.Length];
                candidateBytes = bytes.Skip(offset).Take(signature.Length).ToArray();
                //  I'd not use linq, instead  Array.Copy(bytes, offset, candidateBytes, 0, signature.Length);
                if(signature.Payload.Equals(candidateBytes))                    
                {
                    return createResultObject(true);    
                }
            }                
        }
        return createResultObject();

        FileTypeVerifyResult createResultObject(bool isValid = false)
        {
            return new FileTypeVerifyResult
            {
                Name = Name,
                Description = Description,
                IsVerified = isValid
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are those classes mutable?

Comment: it a scratch at solving the problem, not a gifted complete solution, i am sure it can be suboptimized into immutable for very high intensity processing, nice suggestion

Comment: Immutability isn't about performance (that's just a nice side-effect), it's really about being able to _reason_ about a program's data-flow: Without immutability an object's properties can be arbitrarily modified after instantiation, and it throws-off all guarantees about the object's state made by its ctor (for example, if your `class Signature` is instantiated by someone who forget to set `Payload` then the `Length` property's getter will throw a `NullReferenceException` - a nasty surprise.

Comment: I don't disagree personally, but it is completely off topic to the question where we do not know even if the class at all looks like I am guessing, see not above code. Community member want to see if Linq can be used like that and my suggestion in response is to offer a solve to his problem, but not using a super complex linq.
Obviously a type definition is not per design something which should ever change, so do wee need to protect against it, being a wrong usage pattern, perhaps but probably not. user will new  up type definitions and process very likely a lot of files or just one.